# How to make 10 devices from a single raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need to connect monitors and keyboard to a single raspberry pi board so that each will act as an individual computer.

Comment: get a 20 port usb hub, install [lxd](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction) and provision 10 containers, then just map out devices to the containers. you might have some resource issues though.

Comment: I suspect you are in the wrong place... Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.